# Processing the results of FOR XML PATH stored procedure

Tags: c#, .net, xml, stored-procedures

I want to call a stored procedure in SQL Server 2005 that returns an XML string that can then be passed into another method; I think the below code is right up until the point where I execute the query, but then I get a bit lost...

```
private string GetChartData(string  OC_Ttl1, string OC_OL31, string OC_OL32)
{
    string chartData;

    //Prepare Connection Variables
    SqlConnection conn_Org  = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd_Org = new SqlCommand();

    //Open Connection
    conn_Org.ConnectionString = Set_OrgChartConn();
    conn_Org.Open();

    //Execute Procedure
    cmd_Org.Connection = conn_Org;
    cmd_Org.CommandText = "dbo.usp_CreateOrgDataSet '" + OC_Ttl1 +"','" + OC_OL31 + "'.'" + OC_OL32 +"'";
    cmd_Org.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    chartData = cmd_Org.ExecuteScalar();

    conn_Org.Close();

    return chartData;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What does dbo.usp_CreateOrgDataSet do?

Comment: It returns an XML string, with i want to pass into chartData for use in another method.

Basically it's these lines that i've no idead what i'm doing with


cmd_Org.ExecuteReader();


    chartData = cmd_Org(What goes Here????)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cmd_Org.CommandText = "dbo.usp_CreateOrgDataSet '" + OC_Ttl1 +"','" + OC_OL31 + "'.'" + OC_OL32 +"'";
cmd_Org.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

The above line may cause error. If you set

```
cmd_Org.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

and

```
"dbo.usp_CreateOrgDataSet '" + OC_Ttl1 +"','" + OC_OL31 + "'.'" + OC_OL32 +"'"
```

as `CommandText`, then the `CommandText` will be treated as stored procedure name and the error

> Could not find stored procedure [dbo.usp_CreateOrgDataSet ....]

will occur.

You can set only `dbo.usp_CreateOrgDataSet` as `CommandText` and pass the parameters by e.g.

```
 mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue('@param1', OC_Ttl1);
 mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue('@param2',  OC_OL31);
 mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue('@param3',OC_OL32 );

 cmd_Org.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 chartData = cmd_Org.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: Many Thanks. For reference Visual Studio preferred double quotes around "@param(x)"

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just call `cmd_Org.ExecuteScalar()`?